# If $f(x) = x^\frac 23$, what is $f'(0)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> If $f(x) = x^\frac 23$, what is $f'(0)$?

I think that 
$1.\;f(0) = 0$

$2. \lim\limits_{x\rightarrow +0} f'(x) = \infty$

$3. \lim\limits_{x\rightarrow -0} f'(x) = \infty$

So $f'(0) = \infty$. But actually $f'(x)$ doesn't exist at $x = 0$.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure about 3?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I tried [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=real+plot+x%5E%282%2F3%29), but the function seems to be symmetric by $x = 0$ like $y = |x|$ now. So the right hand side of 3 should be $-\infty$. Then did wolfram alpha fail to plot a correct graph?

Comment: Derivatives need not be continuous. So you need to show $$\lim_{x\to 0+} \frac{f(x)}{x}=\infty.$$ And the same as $x\to 0-.$ But as Hagen points out, you might want to check  $x\to 0-$ carefully.

Comment: Yeah, Wolfram’s plot is wrong. $x^{2/3}$ is positive for $x<0.$

Comment: Note you Wolfram plot says "Assuming the principal root | Use the real‐valued root instead"  So click on the "Use real-valued root" link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, $$ f(x+h)= f(x) + f'(x) \cdot h +o(h)$$

Using $x=0$ we have that $$ f(h)= f(0) + f'(0) \cdot h +o(h) \implies  h^{2/3}= f'(0) \cdot h +o(h)$$

$$ f'(0) = h^{2/3}/h - o(h)/h \implies f'(0)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\;\left(\frac{1}{h}\right)^{1/3}$$

What if you approach $h\rightarrow 0$ by left ($h<0$) and right ($h>0$) ?

Comment: Is there a name for the first equation? I only know the method of increment $$f'(x) = \lim\limits_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{(x+h) - (x)}$$

Comment: It means the same thing, but this alternate view is useful in other cases (like when $h$ is a vector rather than a real number) when it doesn’t make sense to,divide by $h.$ @opol

Comment: The first expression is the standard way to define differenciability ( fits better in higher dimensions, but in one dimension its really the same that you already know )

Comment: If there weren't the term $o(h)$, the equation would be exactly the same as the method of increment. What is the role of that or can you give me any keyword?

Comment: Think that $o(h)$ is some kind of "error" in your linear approximation (derivative). This "error" must goes to zero (even when divided by $h$) when $h$ goes to zero. When this happens you say that $f$ is differentiable.